# Solspace Tag: undefined method Pagination_object::get_template() in mod.tag.php on line 2351

Tags: solspace, solspace-tag

As far as I know I'm running current versions of EE core and all add ons...

- EE 2.9.0
- Solspace Tag 4.2.7
- Structure 3.3.14.5
- Campaigns 2.0.3
- CE Cache 1.9.5

{exp:tag:related_entries} and {exp:tag:tags} are wrapped in {exp:ce_cache:escape}.

On *some* entries I get a white screen when Tags are assigned. I remove all Tags from the entry, save, refresh front-end page and it renders properly.

Add a Tag back to the entry, save, refresh front-end page and I see:

```
undefined method Pagination_object::get_template() in mod.tag.php on line 2351
```

Remove all Tags from the entry, save, refresh front-end page and it renders properly.

What's strange is that this is only happening on *some* entries.

The Solspace tags I'm using in this template are:

```
{exp:tag:related_entries
    channel="self_help_tips"
    entry_id="{structure:page:entry_id}"
    rank_method="total_entries" 
    orderby="relevance"
    limit="20"
}
```

and

```
{exp:tag:tags entry_id="{structure:page:entry_id}"}
```

Please let me know if I'm doing something stupid here, but I can't figure out why only *some* entries are affected.

---

### EDIT Aug 2

I've trimmed down the EE template to just the following tags:

```
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h2>Related Tips</h2>
            {exp:tag:related_entries
                channel="self_help_tips"
                entry_id="{structure:page:entry_id}"
                rank_method="total_entries" 
                orderby="relevance"
                limit="20"
            }
                <p style="line-height:1.2em;"><a href="{url_title_path='tips'}" style="text-decoration:none;">{title}</a></p>
            {/exp:tag:related_entries}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h2>Tags</h2>
            {exp:tag:tags entry_id="{structure:page:entry_id}"}
                {if tag_count == '1'}<ul class="list-inline tags">{/if}
                <li>
                    <a href="{path='tips'}/tag/{websafe_tag}">{tag}</a>
                </li>
                {if tag_count == tag_total_results}</ul>{/if}
            {/exp:tag:tags}
        </div>
```

No pagination is being used in these tags.

Comment: Remove as many variables from the equation as possible while troubleshooting: does `{exp:tag:related_entries}` and `{exp:tag:tags}` work correctly when you're not using that Structure variable in `entry_id=""` and not using `{exp:ce_cache:escape}`? Try your code with hard-coded values instead on a completely, absolutely blank EE template with nothing whatsoever on it besides the code (i.e. no CSS, JS, headers, footers, sidebars, and other 3rd-party plugins). If you can show more of your template data (including pagination), that would also be great.

Comment: I've removed all {exp:cache:it} tags and have narrowed this issue down to this tag pair:

{exp:tag:related_entries
 channel="self_help_tips"
 entry_id="776"
 rank_method="total_entries" 
 orderby="relevance"
 limit="20"
}

Still getting the error "undefined method Pagination_object::get_template() in mod.tag.php on line 2351"

What's interesting is that it works fine on my local instance, but breaks on the production server. I've tried fiddling with CGI and PHP settings with no affect on this issue.

Comment: NOTE: I hardcoded an entry_id and the issue persists

Comment: Since the error mentions pagination, are you using pagination code as well? Can you show us this code? In fact, can you show the whole code for your latest test (i.e. with a hard-coded entry_id)? The difference between your servers is another hint: what are the PHP versions on each?

Comment: I've updated the question above with template code. I've trimmed down the template to ONLY the code above and I'm still seeing the error.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with the code provided above on Aug 2. And you have tried using a hard-coded value instead of {structure:page:entry_id}, is that correct? Are you sure the above code is _absolutely_ the **only** thing on the template? You may need to file a ticket at support.solspace.com for further troubleshooting (EESE is more for "how-to"- or implementation-type questions). Please mention this thread as well.

Comment: Local environment is running MAMP with PHP 5.5.10. Production environment is running PHP 5.5. Yes, I'm sure these tags are the only thing in the template, and yes I tried hard-coding an entry_id but still get the same results. I'll open a ticket at support.solspace.com.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this was an issue of file corruption, or perhaps some files did not upload properly to the production server.

These pages appear to be working fine after I deleted all /third_party and /themes files for the Tag module and re-uploaded them to the server.

I'll keep an eye on it and will post again if anything else comes up. Thank you Solspace for the great support!